# What is this fast growing plant?

Tags: identification, urban-gardening

What is this fast growing plant growing in my pot?

Walking around nature and parks I would collect all sorts of seeds from all sorts of plants and threw them in my pots, so all sorts of things are popping up.

This beauty grew around 60cm in two or three months (NOV DEC JAN), a very fast grower. It's big leaves are maybe 20-30cm long.

And these very small little white flowers grow up close to the main stem.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like "***Solanum americanum***" a member of the **Nightshade family** "**Solanaceae**". The small white flowers in your photos are typical of this family of plants. You will find similar flowers on peppers, tomatoes, and potatoes which are all related. However, this plant is considered to be a weed, and it is poisonous when eaten. Several other members of the family are also poisonous. The two links below should offer additional help and detail.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_americanum

http://www.missouriplants.com/whitealt/Solanum_americanum_page.html

Comment: Erm... No way this could be Yellow belladonna (Atropa belladonna var. lutea) right? Could this be so dangerous I should just eliminate it? I have a 9 month daughter.

Comment: @Johan88: all Solanum are poisonous (also potato berries and green plant). But in general all plants are dangerous. (and all all food). But because this plant has no use, I would remove it (and kids could think berries are edible).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Just the sheer beauty. I like light greens and giant leaves and low maintenance plants that are survivors (unlike other plants that always die on me). God but I love the beauty of this. Sucks that it's poisonous. I wonder how I'm earth it ended up in this pot though. I didn't pick up any berries.